# Load a .html page which should include some data from a .php file

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have three files.
 **1. login.html** - this will take user credentials and send them to a php script.
 **2. check_password.php** - this will validate the user credentials against MySQL database.
 **3. location.html** - this will display location using google map.

**The problem is in integrating these three files.**

For a valid user, location.html should be loaded.

location.html should look something like this on browser
 *part1* - welcome "user name"
*part2* - map

To accomplish part1 of location.html, I am guessing that I should get the user name from check_password.php. I am a beginner. I do not understand how I have to do accomplish this. Please help. DO let me know if I need to provide any other information.

location.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 75%; }
      body { height: 75%; ; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 80%; width: 80%; margin: 10px }
    </style>
</head>

    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=#######&sensor=true">
    </script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    /*code for initialising map*/      
    </script>
body>
    <div id="map-canvas"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am able to accomplish some part of this integration. I am able to send data from login.html to the php script for validation.

Answer (score 3):

1. login.html should contain a form that submits data to check_password.php
2. check_password.php should authenticate the user and mark that they are logged in using a session
3. location.html should be a PHP program and check that the session data indicates an authenticated user before delivering the private HTML

Comment: To add: `login.html` can (should) be a PHP program that checks if a user is already logged in and, if so, immediately redirects to `location.html`. It should also provide some feedback if login failed and you have to redirect the user back to the login form.

Comment: As I am a beginner, I have no idea of how sessions work. Can you please help me with the code for check_password.php to mark the user has logged in and also for part3 of above.

Comment: @AmazingDreams
I have created a login_submit.php file where I am

Comment: @AmazingDreams
I have created a login_submit.php file where I have created a session variable for the valid user(after validating the user) i.e., $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id; I did not understand point 3 above in your comment. Please explain. I might be using this session variable in another php program (pertaining to point 3, as you said), but how is it ensured that the php forms are loaded in proper sequence. I am afraid I did not make my point. I meant after validating user in one php, the next php pgm should load in sequence. How should I ensure this?

Comment: In short, after user validation occurs, the user should see a page that contains a text 

"Welcome username" and the the location map should follow

Please help me in acheiving this. I am working on this since few days.